# Visual Studio 2017 compiles .core dll with a size of 0 bytes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

Perhaps a weird issue, and I'm not entirely sure it is code related.  But I'm writing a project, and if certain files are included, it compiles the .core dll...but it has a size of 0.  Removed the files, it will compile correctly...sometimes.  It is the weirdest thing.

So my question is this: has anyone else seen this issue?  Does .core have issues with things that require interop type services?  I wish I could pinpoint code that causes it, but it seems pretty random.

Comment: How could we know? You posted 0 details of the project and the files. What is even ".core"? Do you mean .NET Core?

Comment: Yes I mean .net core.  As for what causes it, I'm not sure.  I am porting Sharphound to .net core (you can find it on github).  All the libaries (nuget packages) have a .net core equivalent so I honestly have no idea what files are incorrect.

Comment: I needed to mention as well, the port is part of a larger overall port, mostly relating to Active Directory.  My own tool ported just fine.  In sharphound, you find many files, but it seems the primary culprits reside in the "Enumeration" folder/namespace.  What about them is causing this, is the part I have no idea about.

Comment: "Certain files" is vague. "I am porting Sharphound to .net core (you can find it on github)" is also vague as you made unknown modification and triggered the issue. So unless you really decide to reveal enough details (share all the code), this question is impossible to answer.

Comment: I haven't modified any of the files.  If you create a new .net core 2.2 project, copy the files over, add the dependencies it wants, then build.  A dll with a size of 0.  Original project is here:  https://github.com/BloodHoundAD/SharpHound

As far as visual studio is concerned, it says " Build completed" blah blah blah.  This less of me trying to be vague, and more I have no idea what to provide you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Major ID10T error on this one.  Apparently, my AV didn't like the dll so it deleted it without notifying me.  Here is to having dumb moments v_v.

Comment: This means that none of us could replicate the issue, so this question isn't on-topic

Comment: Had I realized this before I asked it I wouldn't have asked the question.  As the original question was has anyone ever experienced this, it was on topic. It just wasn't due to the code or visual studio itself.  Ah the joys of writing penetration test software.